# React Hook updates parent state a step behind

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui, react-hooks

When a functional component updates a prop, the parent's state does not get the new value until another change is made to the picker element.

It goes as such:

Picker loads with date A.

=> I pick date B.

=> Picker renders date B but parent state shows selectedDate of date A.

=> I pick date C.

=> Picker renders date C but parent state shows selectedDate of date B.

**Parent (Stateful Component):**

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
        this.state = { selectedDate: new Date() }   // initializes state
    }

handleDateChange = date => {
        this.setState({ selectedDate: date })   // receives date and updates state
    };

componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log('component did update :', this.state);   // one step behind child state
    };

render() {
  return(
    <DatePicker
        selectedDate={this.state.selectedDate}
        handleDateChange={this.handleDateChange}/>
)}
```

**Child (Function Component):**

```
export default function DatePicker(props) {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState(props.selectedDate);

  const handleDateChange = date => {
        console.log(date)   // shows the correct date

        setSelectedDate(date);                 // updates child state
        props.handleDateChange(selectedDate);  // updates parent state
    };

  return (
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}/>
  )}
```

Comment: Before I answer your question, I would like to know why do you handle the state twice? One at parent level and another at child level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to guarantee something happens when your child's `selectedDate` changes, you can always use an effect.

Our `useEffect` hook here will run the function whenever `selectedDate` or `handleDateChange` are modified.

```
export default function DatePicker(props) {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState(props.selectedDate);
  const { handleDateChange } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    handleDateChange(selectedDate);
  }, [selectedDate, handleDateChange])

  const handleChange = date => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };

  return (
    <KeyboardDatePicker
      value={selectedDate}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear and prompt answer. I had tried useEffect but it appears that my syntax was incorrect. Appreciated!

Comment: btw in this particular case author could just `handleDataChange(date)`(referring to arguments not state) right inside `handleChange` function